# Changing the pdf pagesize for AMS package

Tags: pdf, templates, paper-size, amsbook

I used AMS package with GSM option to write my professor's math book in LaTex. He want to customize the pdf pagesize to 16x24, it is the standard size for that style of book in my country, but I do not know how to customize it.

Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{gsm-l} 
%\special{papersize=160mm, 240mm}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{esvect} 
\usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{lipsum} 
\makeindex
\begin{document} 
\lipsum 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at package `geometry`. There you can put the papersize using a simple interface. For example `papersize={160mm,240mm}`. You should delete the global option `a4paper` tough.

Comment: Thanks @Joannes_B, I have tried as you suggest but geometry package did cut out the blank range and gave me the pdf page which is not symmetry. The distance from the top to the body is quite small than the distance from the body to the bottom (It is 2 to 4). How can I change it?

Comment: Have a look at the [user manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/geometry/geometry.pdf) and the various options within.

Comment: Here is the picture:
http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/5788/5tok.png

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 7):

the `gsm-l.cls` does not deal well with the `geometry` package.
(none of the ams document classes do, since a number of features depend on the fact that
the positioning of the output is always centered horizontally, a requirement for sending
the output directly through an automated plate-maker to prepare plates for the press.)

the three values that are important if it is desired to change the page size are

- `\textheight` -- defaults to 50pc
- `\textwidth` -- defaults to 30pc
- the height of the area devoted to the running head -- defaults to 9.5pt; this,
  in turn, is composed of the pieces

  - `\headheight` -- defaults to 8pt
  - `\headsep` -- defaults to 3pc +5.5pt -`\topskip`
  - `\topskip` -- defaults to 10pt on "inside" pages

since all these values are used in internal calculations (in both `gsm-l.cls`
and `amsbook.cls`, on which the gsm class is based), they must all be set
to "reasonable" values.  however, if the appearance of the running head
area is satisfactory as is, the resetting of the page size can be
accomplished by overriding these two lines from the end of `gsm-l.cls`

```
\textheight=50pc \advance\textheight 9.5\p@
\textwidth=30pc \calclayout
```

by the following:

```
\textheight=24cm \advance\textheight 9.5pt
\textwidth=16cm \calclayout
```

(i'm assuming that the dimensions you give are in cm, not pc.  that's
a very wide page though.)

Comment: Dear @barbara beeton, what does it mean by two options \textheight 9.5 pt and \calclayout ?

Comment: @NguyễnDuyKhánh -- `\calclayout` is not an option. it performs a recalculation of the page position based on a number of named dimensions, among them `\textheight` (the height of the printed area on the page) and `\textwidth` (the width of the normal text area).  other dimensions, established in either `amsbook.cls` or `gsm-l.cls` are involved, and these may or may not need to be changed, but as i said in the answer, it is worth trying first the "simple" change that assumes the defaults.  if other changes are necessary, things get much more complicated. but `geometry` will not do it correctly.

Comment: Dear @barbara beeton, I have changed, but it didn't work in my Xubuntu+Texmaker+Texlive, I don't know what and where it was wrong, but I had changed the `geometry` package option as follows 
\usepackage[papersize={140mm,205mm},inner=20mm, outer=15mm, vmargin=15mm]{geometry}
\geometry{includeheadfoot}
and fortunately, it works. Anyway, thank you very much for your advices, suggestions :)

Comment: @NguyễnDuyKhánh -- i haven't actually tested the modification you report myself, but with other modifications to the dimensions that didn't call `\calclayout` at the end, there have been problems with the two-column index pages.  just a heads up, that if you are creating an index, take a careful look at the output before assuming that everything is all okay.